# Separate merged SQL rows with a comma

Tags: php, sql, merge, rows

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my retrieved values from an SQL query into the correct format.

I've managed to join multiple rows into the one value, however I am not sure how to make it separate each of the values with a comma. Essentially I need all the ID's of a product to be retrieved as, for example, if the database had values of '5,6,9,1' '1,3,4' and '2,1' I want it to throw a comma in between each like -> '5,6,9,1,1,3,4,2,1' instead is doing something more like -> '5,6,911,3,42,1' which is what it is doing at the moment.

The code I'm using is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$hist = "SELECT ORDITEMS FROM cust_orderc WHERE ORDDATE > 
to_date('".$olddate."','dd/mm/yyyy')";


$histitem = OCIParse($db, $hist);
OCIExecute($histitem);

while($row = oci_fetch_array($histitem)){
    $pastitem .= $row['ORDITEMS'];  
}

echo "$pastitem";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do same in `oracle` using `LISTAGG`

```
$hist = "SELECT LISTAGG(ORDITEMS) as ORDITEMS FROM cust_orderc WHERE ORDDATE > to_date('".$olddate."','dd/mm/yyyy')";
```

**Edit** OR PHP way

```
$pastitem = '';
while($row = oci_fetch_array($histitem)){
    $pastitem .= $row['ORDITEMS'] . ',';  
}
$pastitem = trim($pastitem, ",");
echo $pastitem;
```

Comment: For an oracle database, the equivalent function is `wm_concat()`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks, I never noticed this query related with oracle database. :)

Comment: wm_concat() was never (IIRC) officially documented or supported; I believe Oracle 11g has the `LISTAGG()` function for the same purpose

Comment: @MarkBaker included both ways. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, but it seems the database version at my Uni does not support that command. Most likely they haven't updated in a while. All I get is ORA-00904 "WM_CONCAT": Invalid Identifier error. Is there a way around it?

Comment: @JustKoz So use PHP way. :)

Comment: Ah didn't realise you added that there.. Thank you so so much!! That did the trick beautifully :D I would upvote if I could, don't have 15 reputation yet >.<

Comment: Oh one more question sorry, with the last trim command, i get results of "5,3,5,35,3,5,3" but if I remove it I get "5,3,5,35,3,5,3," with that last comma on the end. Have I done something wrong? I'm fairly sure it's doubling the entire value, and should just be "5,3,5,3".

Comment: @JustKoz `trim` is used to remove the last comma from string.

Comment: Do you know why it's duplicating the results? It's coming up with 5,3,5,35,3,5,3 instead of just 5,3,5,3. Sorry to be a pain with this, it's just beyond my level of knowledge in PHP. Never mind, I'm an idiot! Forgot about some test code I had further down which was affecting the results. Thanks again!!

Comment: @JustKoz Because your query gives you same result. Check the result in phpmyadmin by running same query.